# Merge multiple subdirectories from Google Takeout recursively on Windows 10 and Linux

Tags: command-line, windows-explorer

I am trying to merge the contents of the ZIPs from my Google Takeout. There are plenty of ZIPs.
They are all extracted to one individual directory. Each of these directories has one sub-directory "Takeout" which then can have multiple subdirectories.
These sub-sub directories can re-appear in the other "Takeout" folders.

Example:

```
Folder1/Takeout/Google Drive/a
Folder1/Takeout/Google Photos/a
Folder2/Takeout/Google Drive/b
Folder3/Takeout/Google Drive/c
Folder4/Takeout/Google Drive/d
```

Should be turned into

```
NewFolder/Takeout/Google Drive/a
NewFolder/Takeout/Google Drive/b
NewFolder/Takeout/Google Drive/c
NewFolder/Takeout/Google Drive/d
NewFolder/Takeout/Google Photos/a
```

How do I do that efficiently on Windows 10 and Ubuntu based Linuxes (preferably via commandline)?

Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].